# Javascript - accessing global vars from a child window

Tags: javascript

When a window opens a child window with

```
    var someVar = "someValue";
    newWin = window.open("somepage.html","","");
```

The child window can access the parent's global variables

```
    var x = window.opener.someVar;
    alert(x);
```

This works fine (child alerts "someValue") in Firefox 18, IE6, IE7, Opera 11.52, Safari 5.1.1  But it fails in Chrome 24.0 (and maybe newer Safaris too?), when it alerts "undefined".

Yikes!  Anyone else experience this?  Any workarounds?

---

In the past, I have been able to access global vars either direction, and execute functions in the other window too.  I'd hate to see this functionality going away.
Dave

Comment: Are you testing this on a server, or with `file://` URLs?

Answer (score 2):

It still appears to be working for me.  On this site, try this for yourself on this page in the console in Chrome:

```
 this.test = "hello"
 window.open(window.location.href) //opens the same page
```

(You'll have to make sure popups are allowed, so you may have to do it twice).  Then, in the popup's console:

```
 console.log(window.opener.test)
```

You'll see "hello".

That said, I have noticed that Chrome is the strictest when it comes to cross domain access *especially* when developing a site locally (if you're just accessing html files directly through the file system with file://, for instance).  I like to develop in Chrome, and if I'm developing locally I need to run some sort of web server to serve the pages, while Firefox will happily let me access them directly through the file system and doesn't complain about XSS issues.

Comment: loganfsmyth and lmortenson

Comment: loganfsmyth and @lmortenson,

Thank you! Yes, I'm doing file:// I just uploaded it to my server, and it works fine there. Additionally, in the parent window, I can still execute a function on the child. Looks like bi-directional everything will work fine there.

BUT, this is a local app - no server involved.  Will provide longer answer in the AM when S.O. allows me to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

Yes, I'm doing file://  I just uploaded it to my server, and it works fine there.  Additionally, in the parent window, I can still execute a function on the child.  Looks like bi-directional everything will work fine on a server.

Here's my scenario.  I'm developing an add-on for a Windows program BeerSmith2 ([Beer Homebrewing program](http://beersmith.com)).  This windows app uses a small-sized "captive" browser (the IE on your computer) to display "reports" from the windows app.  My add-on needs to break out of the application's small captive browser into a full screen browser (same IE), and pass a large number of variables from the captive to the full-screen.

So there's no server involved, and I really only need to support IE, but I'm trying to keep it cross-browser so that my add-on will also work with the Mac version of BeerSmith2 in the future.  I develop in Firefox, then make it work in IE6 (if it works on IE6, it'll work on anything), then final tweak in IE-later/Opera/Safari/Chrome which usually only have minor difficulties.

Imagine my terror when the whole program (a couple thousand of lines of JS code) failed utterly on the latest Chrome. Since there's no server, I can't do Ajax, and I can't think of any other way to do this.  So I think I'm stuck.  I hope Safafi doesn't follow suit.

IE has a nasty popup warning about running JS in file://'s, but you can turn that off.  Chrome just silently fails on this passing variables between windows, and I don't think it gives you any option.  Wow, Microsoft actually did something the right way!

Thanks for your help.
Dave